# Help using core Template Route and Template Route Manager w/ pagination

Tags: url, template-routes

I'm tying to figure out how to use the new core [Template Route](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/template_routes.html) feature.

I have the following templates:

- gear.group/brand.html
- gear.group/brand_entry.html

I have the following urls:

- /gear/brand/orange/
- /gear/brand/orange/P20
- /gear/brand/orange/my_entry_title

*Note: segment_3 or orange in this case could be any category and should be considered dynamic*

I tried to have one template for the first two urls above and another one for the entry itself. I tried routes in the [Template Route Manager](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/template_route_manager.html) like you see in the image below though, without success:

[image: template routes]

[[full image]](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdni0282fbfzfg5/Screenshot%202014-08-21%2018.20.36.png)

Or I could use one template instead of two and a conditional of some sort though, I'm not sure how at this point.